# Dados das requisições não estão retornando corretamente

Tags: javascript, json, api

Estou tentando criar um front-end com base na API do star wars, meu plano era criar um objeto para então mostrar na tela.
Quando faço uma requisição(https://swapi.co/films  por exemplo),algumas propriedades do objeto vem como um array de links.
Então pensei em chamar função dentro da requisição para fazer outras requisições usando o AXIOS, porem quando retorno os dados, eles voltam todos juntos.Como posso fazer que as propriedades dos objetos recebam os dados corretamente?

Meu código segue abaixo:

```
const urlAPI = 'https://swapi.co/api/'


async function getInformation(arrayURL) {

    arrayData = []
    promisses = []
    arrayURL.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element)
        const promisse = axios(element)
            .then(response => response)
            .then(resp => arrayData.push(resp.name))
        promisses.push(promisse)
    })
    axios.all(promisses)
    console.log(arrayData)
    return await arrayData;

}


axios.get(`${urlAPI}films`)
    .then(response => {
        return (response.data.results)
    })
    .then(resp => {
        // console.log(resp)
        resp.forEach(element => {
            if (element.hasOwnProperty('planets')) {
                element.planets = getInformation(element.planets)
                console.log(element.planets)
            }


        })

    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

[image: Em cada console.log ele deveria mostrar os nomes dos planetas, mas mostra apenas na ultima chamada e ainda fora de ordem]

Comment: Como assim "voltam todos juntos"? Pode dar um exemplo?

Comment: Pelo código, cada conjunto de requisições que chamo através da função getInformation devia devolver os valores ao 'element.planets' de cada 'element', no entanto ele só devolve ao ultimo 'element' e todos juntos e de maneira desorganizada.

Comment: Em cada console.log, deveria estar mostrando os nomes dos planetas que chamei da função getInformation, mas ele mostra vazio. Só no ultimo que ele mostra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem muitos erros a respeito do tratamento de assincronismo nesse código, tanto que fica até difícil descrever todo o fluxo do código para explicar como ele chegou nesse resultado final.

Um erro notável está aqui:

```
element.planets = getInformation(element.planets)
```

`getInformation` é uma função assíncrona, ela vai te retornar uma `Promise`, não um array de planetas, mas em nenhum ponto você espera pela resolução dessa promise.

A implementação da função `getInformation` também está confusa, você popula um array `promisse` com todas as suas requisições, depois usa `axios.all(promisses)` para esperar a resolução das promises, mas não usa nem `await`, nem `then()`, ou seja, não espera de fato pela resolução, e então finalmente você faz `await arrayData`. Por quê? Eu não sei o que você imaginou, mas utilizar `await` num array não tem efeito nenhum.

A sua ideia no entanto parece estar correta, se entendi corretamente. Vou tentar adaptar o código utilizando `fetch` para maior acessibilidade aqui no site, a única diferença é que você usará `axios.get(url)` ao invés de `fetch(url).then(r => r.json())`

```js
const urlAPI = 'https://swapi.co/api/'

function getInformation(arrayURL) {
  // Com o método map, gero um array de promises que correspondem as requisições
  // Essa função não precisa ser assíncrona, pois não precisamos dos dados das
  // requisições aqui, e portanto não precisamos esperar pela resolução
  const arrayPromise = arrayURL.map(url => fetch(url).then(r => r.json()))
  return Promise.all(arrayPromise)
}

async function fetchData() {
  const response = await fetch(`${urlAPI}films`).then(r => r.json())
  
  // Primeiro loop, faço todas as requisições, mas não espero por suas resoluções
  // dessa forma não preciso esperar pela primeira requisição acabar antes de começar a próxima
  for (const result of response.results) {
    result.planets = getInformation(result.planets)
  }

  // Agora que todas as requisições já foram enviadas, posso esperar pela resolução uma a uma
  for (const result of response.results) {
    result.planets = await result.planets
  }

  console.log(response)
}

fetchData()
```

Esse código requer um esforço adicional para optimizar o tempo de resposta. Você poderia apenas fazer uma requisição de cada vez e esperar pela resposta, seria mais simples, mas devido a quantidade de requisições nesse código, isso atrapalharia a experiência do usuário.